# 6.5 inch (iPhone XS Max, iPhone XR) screenshot is required

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, screenshot

For earlier versions of my app, I was able to submit an app with just a single device screenshot that was on 5.5 inch (iPhone 6s Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 8 Plus).

But, while uploading an update to the app now, got to know that 6.5 inch (iPhone XS Max, iPhone XR) screenshot is also required in addition to the existing 5.5-inch display screenshot.

I just want to know is this a recent change in the requirement by Apple or am I missing on something?

Moreover, is there any workaround or alternate available if I don't have iPhone XR or XS Max?

Comment: Yes, it's mandatory since March 27. You can find more details here: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=03202019a

Comment: Run your app on the iPhone XS Max simulator and take screenshots from there.

Comment: @OmarChaabouni but I doesn't accept iPhone XR screenshots, it says size is incorrect

Comment: just change screenshots size according given by the apple document it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems especially aged to answer now as No good answer is here. I think this will be useful to new Apple developers or flutter developers. Many need to accomplish this issue as they may not have a mac book or many apple resources.

We have two options. The first one is to use a different simulator on Xcode & MacBook or Resize screenshots images. One can use **img2go**.com to do this.

For the first choice, suggested simulator use

1. Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max for 6.5
2. Apple iPhone 8 Plus for 5.5

For the second option, Take screenshots on any iPhone and resize them as

1. iPhone 6.5" Display (414 x 896 px)
2. iPhone 5.5" Display (414 x 736 px)

Please keep in mind that applications' resized screenshots work only if the app is a 100% responsive application.

Answer (score -2):

i am sorry for previious answer
it is required now, if after taking screnshot from simulator or real device you are still getting error saying wrong size you go to any photo editor
i am using sketch and make a rectangle of size given by apple and insert your screenshot into that rectangle and export that rectangle as a png then you will be able to upload that

Comment: I've tried. It's not like that. It requires iPhone XR or XS Max screenshots only